# Negative Lookahead Faults Regex

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression:

```
^\/admin\/(?!(e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5)).*$
```

My input string:

```
/admin/e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5
```

As I understand, negative lookahead should check if a group `(e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5)` has a match, or am I incorrect?

Since input string has a group match, why does negative lookahead not work? By that I mean that I expect my regex to `e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5` to match input string `e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5`.

Removing negative lookahead makes this regex work correctly.

[Tested with regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Y1l2qR/2)

Comment: You seem to need `(?!.*e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5$)`

Comment: Not quite, your regex would match any user, my regex must match when it's admin and UID is the same, removing lookahead gives this result. But I can't figure out why (since it's supposed to work with lookahead).

Comment: That's not clear: do you need to match `/admin/e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5` or not?

Comment: A negative lookahead asserts, that a certain pattern can't be matched from the curernt position, in your case `e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5`. As this assertion fails, the whole match is discarded.Do y ou need a positive lookahead maybe?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew what's not clear? Let's say it's another user, `user1/e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5` your regex would match both it and `admin/e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5`. That's incorrect.

Comment: and next to Sebastian Proske's comment: you say `Since input string has a group match`. You don't, because it's inside a looahead.

Comment: @Marc Lambrichs I might have misunderstood the regex, since it's the first time I've had the pleasure of dealing with negative lookahead and now I'm trying to find why was this used and why it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The takeway message of this question is: a lookaround matches a **position**, not a string.

```
(?!e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5)
```

will match any position, that is **not** followed by `e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5`.

Which means, that:

```
^\/admin\/(?!(e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5)).*$
```

will match:

```
/admin/abc
```

and even:

```
/admin/e99bb49498c5
```

but not:

```
/admin/e06772ed-7575-4cd4-8cc6-e99bb49498c5/daffdakjf;adjk;af
```

This is exactly the explanation why there is a match whenever you get rid of the `?!`. The string matches **exactly**.

Next, you can lose the parentheses inside your lookahead, they do not have their usual function of grouping here.

Comment: _Next, you can lose the parentheses inside your lookahead, they do not have their usual function of grouping here._ That is not necessarily true, they do still capture and in other scenarions (given the regex engine of choice supports this) be used for backreferences and conditionals. In positive lookaheads you can still acces the captured values in the resulting match and in replace operations.

Comment: @SebastianProske Be specific.

Comment: In e.g. PCRE you can create a lookahead like `(?!(a)\1)` where the grouping is still relevant. You can also create a positive lookahead like `(?=(a))` and refer to that group in the match and for replacements. Round brackets still form captured groups in lookahead scenarios.

Comment: Yes. That's *inside* your negative lookahead. And that's not what we're talking about here in this question.

Comment: You write _, they do not have their usual function of grouping here._ but exactly that is still the case, they do still form groups. Yes you can remove them and don't hurt this particular pattern, but you can't generalize it that way.

Comment: I guess I have stress again: *here* as in, *in this case*.